using DynDns for IPs behind a NATrouter - security concerns?
In my home network behind NAT router, I have an owncloud server, with the very creative name "owncloud". It shall stay private and inaccessible from the internet. It is OK, if the sync only works when I am at home.
Question: When I am outside of home, and my phone tries to connect with "ownloud" e.g. on a foreign Wifi - could it happen that some bad guy in the wifi creates a server with the same name, sniffs my username/password (could he do this???) and even manipulate the data by spoofing an own oncloud server?
To be able to create a SSL connection and get rid of the browser warnings (normal letsencrypt only works on public servers), I read about using a Dynamic DNS provider and point to the INTERNAL IP, like 192.168.2.xxx - and do the letsencrypt authentication via the DNS record.
https://dev.to/ietxaniz/how-to-implement-https-in-local-networks-using-lets-encrypt-4eh
Question: Also here, outside of home, the phone will try to connect to an IP which does not exist. Or may exist but point to a different server.
Are there any security concerns by doing so?
And most important - if yes, is there any way to overcome this instead of publically hosting the whole server on a domain which is really owned by me?

Yes, server impersonation is very much plausible, and even likely. Public key TLS/SSL certs were designed to prevent this issue. Just because you have a certificate doesn’t make your server public, though.

@security_paranoid Thanks for the hint. But would this mean, a Dynamic DNS provider could solve this issue? In my understanding I am the only person who is able to prove ownage of the subdomain, so if somebody else is spoofing the IP, I would get a certificate error?

It seems you're using shortened versions of words inconsistently. "Intern" is the one I'm most confused by. Please edit your post to use fully spelled out words so we will understand more clearly what you're asking.

@music2myear - sorry what would be the best word for it?
intern means an address behind a NAT router which is only accessible when connected to my router. Like 192.168.2.xxx

That's called "internal".

Thanks for the comment, I have edited the description


Question: Also here, outside of home, the phone will try to connect to an IP which does not exist. Or may exist but point to a different server. Are there any security concerns by doing so?
And most important - if yes, is there any way to overcome this instead of publically hosting the whole server on a domain which is really owned by me?

Well, that's the whole purpose of the LetsEncrypt TLS certificates that you're setting up. Their whole point is to bind a hostname to a specific server that owns a specific private key. So if your OwnCloud server requires TLS, and you connect to a specific DNS name with certificate validation, then the phone will refuse to connect to the "wrong" server even if it happens to have the same internal IP address. (It will still try though, as otherwise it can't see the certificate until it starts connecting.)
Though of course it relies on all your phone apps actually validating the certificates... some apps don't. I've seen a few which assume that even if the user has a certificate set up, it's going to be a bogus one, so the "[✔] SSL" checkbox isn't worth much.
A somewhat more secure method might be a combination of:

IPv6 at your home LAN. It doesn't necessarily need to be ISP-provided global addresses – it would be enough to set up private "ULA" fdXX:XXXX:... addresses (the IPv6 equivalent of 192.168), and as long as you choose the subnet prefix randomly, it'll have an incredibly low chance of accidentally colliding with another LAN's private addresses.
(It's still easy for someone to see which addresses your phone is trying to reach, and then to deliberately set up a fake server with the same address, but at least it raises the bar to requiring actual intent.)

Self-hosted always-on VPN, e.g. Tailscale/WireGuard/ZeroTier, when you're anywhere outside your home network. Configure it to route only your LAN address prefix, and the phone's OS will ensure that all traffic to those addresses go through the secure VPN tunnel to your home network and nowhere else.
(This slightly depends on the LAN address prefix being reasonably unique; perhaps not necessarily IPv6, but at least choose one that you don't expect to find in someone else's LAN.)
An added advantage of having a VPN to your home is that it'll work even for protocols that don't use TLS/SSL, e.g. file access through SMB2.


